# create software that make my file all time being used

Tags: android, copy-paste

I want to create software that can make my file all time being used to prevent copying. means whenever someone try to copy it it will show that file being used somewhere else. I seen this type of software in some places. that will make file  uncopyable. it will make it all time used. means all file being opened somewhere so you can't copy it.

I want make this type and store it in sd card. so whenever any one use my sd card in his computer than it will show a being used error. means whenever he attach sd card to computer. file will automatically opened somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried this before but create a service class and open the file in the service using an input stream

```
File file = <filepath>


InputStream in = null;
try{
 in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
 ...
finally {
 if (in != null) {
   in.close();
 }
```

}
 }
Not sure if it prevents copying or not

Comment: But what script i want to add or in which language? that will automatically run(by default) when sd card attach?

Comment: Means which file i can put in my sd card so when someone attach in his device like android or pc than script automatically(by default) execute on sd card mount or detect. in that script i can put code that open all file in background..

Comment: it is in java as android apps are normally coded in java ,you need to create an android app that has a service that constantly keep the file occupied all the time,and yes once you create this service it will run even if there is an sdcard or not until you stop it

Comment: you have to accept an answer if you found a solution as it will be helpful for others

Comment: But how to install that app from sd card itself without user permission. The point is people can't copy it. i will give my file and app in his sd card when he insert or mount sd card app should automatically install in his device in background.